# matplotlib support failed in PyCharm on OSX

Tags: matplotlib, pycharm

Any idea how to fix this ? How can I debug what might be the problem ? This does not seem to help : https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-15520

I get this in the console:

```
Python 2.6.9 (unknown, Jul 14 2015, 19:46:31) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)] on darwin
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
Matplotlib support failed
```

The backend is :

```
>>> import matplotlib
>>> print(matplotlib.rcParams['backend'])
MacOSX
```

Comment: I get this error with matplotlib version 3.2.1. I tried older versions of matplotlib in reverse realease order, but still same error. Anyone got suggestions why this could be happening? I am using Python 3.7.7.

Comment: I upgraded my version of Pycharm today tp 2020.1 and this error was fixed. So far so good.

Answer (score 6):

Try rolling back matplotlib to version: 2.1.2

You can do that with pip for example:

```
pip install matplotlib==2.1.2
```

Jetbrains is trying to fix this. See the following post:
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000108710-Matplotlib-support-failed